# Find sizeof type object ?

Tags: c#

I define this struct

```
public enum E1 : byte
{
    A,
    B,
    C
}

public enum E2 : byte
{
    D,
    E,
    F
}

[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, Pack=4)]
public struct SomeStruct
{
    public Int32  _var1; //4 byte
    public E1     _var2; //1 byte(because Pack is 4 this will take 4 byte)
    public E2     _var3; //1 byte(because Pack is 4 this will take 4 byte) 
    public UInt64 _var4; //8 byte
}
```

Now, because i add the StructLayout attribute with Pack=4 i expect that each of the variable that i define will keep the alignment of data fields to be 4.

So i expect that the

```
 int val = Marshal.SizeOf( typeof( SomeStruct ) );
```

but i check the code and i found that val is 16

So how it can be ?
Where is my misunderstanding ?

Comment: `4+1+1+8=14` with `Pack=4` it is `16`

Comment: @Yanshof: derive the `enum`s from `uint`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`SizeOf` specifies the size in **bytes**.

Now if we do the math we see that:

- An `Int32` has `32` bits thus `4` bytes.
- An `Int64` has `64` bits thus `8` bytes.
- Both `enum`s are encoded on a byte, thus `1` byte.

Together that's `1+1+4+8` thus `14` bytes.

**But**: most systems don't like to work with bytes: they fetch and store data using **words** (16 bit), or **dwords** (32 bit). Since minimizing the data structure would result in operations to cut off data and reinstert it, it is packed with tailing zeros.

If you thus work on such system, the compiler might like to pack data together in chunks of `16` bit (or higher). These are easier: if you for instance want to access an element in an array, it doesn't have to fetch two words into memory because the struct is splitted among the words.

An experiment to demonstrate how the data is packed:

```
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

namespace Foo {

    public enum E1 : byte
    {
        A,
        B,
        C
    }

    public enum E2 : byte
    {
        D,
        E,
        F
    }


    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential,Pack=4)]
    public struct SomeStruct
    {
        public int  _var1; //4 byte
        public byte     _var2; //1 byte(because Pack is 4 this will take 4 byte)
        public byte     _var3; //1 byte(because Pack is 4 this will take 4 byte) 
        public ulong _var4; //8 byte

        public SomeStruct (int var1, byte var2, byte var3, ulong var4) {
             this._var1 = var1;
             this._var2 = var2;
             this._var3 = var3;
             this._var4 = var4;
        }

    }

}

Foo.SomeStruct i = new Foo.SomeStruct(1302,5,17,1425);
Marshal.SizeOf( typeof( Foo.SomeStruct ) );
sizeof(Foo.SomeStruct);
int size = sizeof(Foo.SomeStruct);
byte[] result = new byte[size];
IntPtr buffer = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(size);
Marshal.StructureToPtr(i, buffer, false);
Marshal.Copy(buffer, result, 0, size);
```

results in:

```
{ 22, 5, 0, 0, 5, 17, 0, 0, 145, 5, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 }
```

The struct is thus encoded as:

```
0                32   40   48       64                              128
+----------------+----+----+--------+--------------------------------+
| _var1          | _v2| _v3| ------ | _var4                          |
+----------------+----+----+--------+--------------------------------+
```

If you use `int`/`uint` to encode the variable, one gets:

```
{ 22, 5, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 145, 5, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 }
```

or:

```
0       32        64       96      128              192
+--------+--------+--------+--------+----------------+
| _var1  |  _var2 | _var3  | ------ | _var4          |
+--------+--------+--------+--------+----------------+
```

Comment: The documentation seems to interpret the `Pack` value differently: it means that every field begins at offset `n*2` where `n` is the 0-based count of the element. For example: with `Pack = 2`, field 1 starts at offset 0, field 2 at offset 2, field 3 at offset 4, etc. Essentially: every single field is padded. However your answer indicates that all fields are grouped together and then padded at the end. What am I misinterpreting?

Comment: @JeroenVannevel: based on some experiments, It seems that - at least the Mono compiler - ignores the packing attribute.